# Csv file not loading into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, csv

This is the code that is failing. The table on the data base works fine. But I am not able to load new data.

```
<!--php to upload csv file not working as written below-->  
<?php  

    include("DBconnection.php");

$sql= "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'kb-listings.csv'
    INTO TABLE `listings-table`
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
    (MLS, STATUS, ENTRY, SUB, ADDRESS, ZIP, BEDS, BATHS, HBATHS, SQFT-LIV, LOT-SQFT, ORIG-LP, LIST-PRICE, POOL, DOM, SALE-PRICE, M-FEE, TAXES, CLOSING, VIEW, UNIT-VIEW, OFFICE, YEAR-BUILT, GARAGE, PARK, TYPE, WF, AMEN, REMARKS)";


    if($result =mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){echo "success";}
    else 
        echo "failure";
    mysqli_close($conn);

    ?>
```

Comment: Instead of printing failure, you could print the actual MySQL error message and you would not have to guess what's went wrong...

Comment: What happens when you try. Are you getting success or failure? If you're getting failure, then check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) instead of giving a generic message.

Comment: can you more explain the problem . it's not enough to help you

Comment: here is my error message:                                                                                           You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-LIV, LOT-SQFT, ORIG-LP, LIST-PRICE, POOL, DOM, SALE-PRICE, M-FEE, TAXES, CLOSIN' at line 5

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to escape the `"` you can just write like this `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'`

Comment: A Colonna,  I get a php  error if I dont escape the "

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all of the answers. Each answer helped me get to a solution in different ways.
 1. I added mysqli_error()  and that led me to -  a syntax problem with my fields.
 2. I checked online and found that using dashes in field names creates problems 
    because the dashes have to be escaped.

Once I fixed the field names everything worked perfect.  I disagree with the usual comments of "this has been answered before in another post". My problem although pretty basic may trip up other beginner programmers out there.